Homotopy equivalent spaces have the same Homology groups
I'm reading "Algebraic Topology" by Hatcher, and in page 111 he writes the theorem:

Theorem 2.10: if two maps $f$,$g$: $X \rightarrow Y$ are homotopic, then they induce the same homomorphism $f_*=g_*$

I understand the proof ad the construction of the prism operator, however i was wondering if there is a proof along the lines:

let $f_t$ be a homotopy between $f_0,f_1$ then $(f_t)_*$ induce maps from $C_n(X)$ to $C_n(Y)$ commuting with the boundary map and hence induce maps from $H_n(X)$ to $H_n(Y)$, however note that the family $(f_t)_*$ induce "continuous" maps (with respect to $t$) from $C_n(X)$ to $C_n(Y)$ and hence after quotienting the maps $(f_t)_*: H_n(X) \rightarrow H_n(Y)$ must be continuous as well, however the topology on $H_n(X)$ is discrete and hence all the induced maps are equal.

I do understand the argument has several flaws, but nevertheless I think there should exist a proof along these lines.
Any help is appreciated
Edit1:
The topology on $\hom(\Delta^n,X)$ that I have in mid is the following, let $\alpha \in \hom(\Delta^n,X)$ we define n-hoods of $\alpha$, lets $U_1,\dots,U_k$ be an open cover of $\alpha(\Delta)$ we define the nhoods around $\alpha$ as follows:
$$\mathcal{U}_\alpha=\{\{\beta| \beta(\alpha^{-1}(U_i)) \subseteq U_i\}| U_1,\dots,U_k \text{ are covers of } \alpha(\Delta) \}$$
clearly for any $A \in \mathcal{U}_\alpha$ we have $\alpha \in A$
I'm currently trying to prove the next part to show this indeed gives a topology
then I will induce a topology on $C_n(X)$ in which the open sets are translation invariant, so I just need to define the nhood basis around 0, which is defnie to be:
$$\mathcal{U}=\{\{\sum_{i=1}^n(\alpha_i - \beta_i)|\beta_i \in U_{V_{1,i},\dots,V_{k_i,i},\alpha_i} \in \mathcal{U}_{\alpha_i}\}| V_{1,i},\dots,V_{k_i,i} \text{ are covers of } \alpha_i(\Delta)\}$$

One problem with the approach is the last line: there are homology theories in which $H_n(X)$ is not discrete (e.g., singular homology with real coefficients). You can actually regard the prism approach as an attempt to patch up this argument about a "continuously-varying family" of maps from $C_n(X)$ to $C_n(Y)$, or perhaps treat it as a model for how to work around the challenges of formalizing such intuitions.

Have you tried endowing $C_n(X)$ with candidate topologies that would make your argument work?

The trouble is that (I think) the discrete topology on $C_n(X)$ does not work, since given two $n$-simplices $\sigma\colon \Delta^n\to X$ and $\sigma'\colon \Delta^n\to Y$, the set ${t\in[0,1]:\sigma\circ f_t=\sigma'}\subset [0,1]$ need not be open. It would be interesting to make this work though.

@Plop I have tried a toplogy using the compactness of the $\Delta$ but couldn't completly define it. I will write my approach in the problem in some minutes.
